# IF function for if x > y, but < yz multiple by b

Tags: excel, google-sheets

So this is what I’m trying to do. If the percent of an output (let’s call it A1) is <75% multiply by 0. If it’s between 75-100% multiply by 1, if it’s between 100-150% multiply by 2, etc.

Comment: "But" in logic are And, you can use the AND function.

Comment: you can use MATCH: `=A1*MATCH(A1,{75,100})`

Comment: What if **A1** is less than 75?

Comment: So this is what I’m trying to do. If the percent of an output (let’s call it A1) is  <75% multiply by 0. If it’s between 75-100% multiply by 1, if it’s between 100-150% multiply by 2, etc.

Comment: Right now I have IF(A1>0.75, IF(A1<1,B1*1),AND(A1>1, IF(A1<1.5,B1*2))) 

B1 = a controlled number I want to multiply.

Comment: With that formula above, it seems to work for a percent within 75-100. However, if it’s between 100-150 it comes back as “false”

Comment: please [edit] the post instead of adding clarification in the comments.

Comment: Use: `=B1*(MATCH(A1,{0,0.75,1,1.50})-1)` and keep adding the lower threshold for other deliniations.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner's `MATCH` answer is already good in the comments. But if you are looking for a plain `IF` function:

```
=IF(A1 < 0.75, 0,
IF(A1 < 1, B1, 
IF(A1 < 1.5, B1 * 2)))
```

Although, I recommend using `IFS` for readability since we can opt not to include else values due to the non-conflicting conditions.

```
=IFS(
A1 < 0.75, 0,
A1 < 1, B1,
A1 < 1.5, B1 * 2
)
```

#### Sample Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Sheets read the formula left to right (top to bottom) so if it doesn't match the first condition, it will just proceed to the next one.
- Feel free to adjust the ranges if it must be inclusive to the upper limit. (e.g `<` to `<=`)
- Notice that 1st and 2nd values were not multiplied by 0 and 1, as we all know, the result would be 0 and the number itself respectively thus I opted from multiplying B1 to those numbers.
- Sample outputs in the sheet shown are respective to their rows.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1, {0.75, 0; 1, B1; 1.5, B1*2}, 2, 0)))
```